# Python (numpy) sort character order?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

What is the sorting order of characters in Python (or numpy)? is there any table?

```
[In] : np.sort(["a","c","b","-"])
[Out]: array(['-', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
       dtype='|S1')
[In] : np.sort(["a","c","b","78"])
[Out]: array(['78', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 
       dtype='|S1')
```

Is there anything which would sort after the letters? Or, alternately, how is this order decided?
I tried a lot of special characters, they all sort in the front.

```
sorted()
```

behaves the same way.

Comment: The `~`, `{`, `|`, `}` characters and the `del` special character are the only characters that come after letters in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin `ord()` returns the value of an 8-bit character.

Try `ord('a')` etc.

```
In [1]: ord('a')
Out[1]: 97

In [2]: ord('&')
Out[2]: 38
```

`chr(97)` is the inverse of `ord('a')`

```
In [3]: table = {i: chr(i) for i in xrange(i)}

In [4]: table
...
```